# wagtail customizing generated admin from for parentalkey

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

In Wagtail document, I find an explanatory example showing how you can customize the behavior of admin form adding a few validation and save perks:

```
from django import forms
import geocoder  # not in Wagtail, for example only - http://geocoder.readthedocs.io/
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from wagtail.admin.forms import WagtailAdminPageForm
from wagtail.core.models import Page


class EventPageForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):
    address = forms.CharField()

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()

        # Make sure that the event starts before it ends
        start_date = cleaned_data['start_date']
        end_date = cleaned_data['end_date']
        if start_date and end_date and start_date > end_date:
            self.add_error('end_date', 'The end date must be after the start date')

        return cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        page = super().save(commit=False)

        # Update the duration field from the submitted dates
        page.duration = (page.end_date - page.start_date).days

        # Fetch the location by geocoding the address
        page.location = geocoder.arcgis(self.cleaned_data['address'])

        if commit:
            page.save()
        return page


class EventPage(Page):
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    content_panels = [
        FieldPanel('title'),
        FieldPanel('start_date'),
        FieldPanel('end_date'),
        FieldPanel('address'),
    ]
    base_form_class = EventPageForm
```

All and all it shows how you can ensure date fields are set correct before saving the form and so on. Great, **my question then will be if the form contains a parentalkey field ??** like this:

```
class EventPage(Page):
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    content_panels = [
        FieldPanel('title'),
        FieldPanel('start_date'),
        FieldPanel('end_date'),
        FieldPanel('address'),
        InlinePanel('image_relations')
    ]
    base_form_class = EventPageForm

class EventPageImageRelations(Orderable):
   parent = ParentalKey(
        EventPage,
        related_name="image_relations",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='+'
    )
   date = models.DateField()
    panels = [
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
        FieldPanel('date')
    ]
```

Now, imagine that you'd like to run a check **before saving** to ensure that the designated date for each image is enter after the start_date. 
I find this challenging how can get the value on a form for a foreign key relation!

Comment: I have a similar challenge. Were you able to work out a solution for custom validation with ParentKey relationships?